# html input type="date" not working exactly on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, datepicker, calendar

I used html5 input type="date" https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp

On the Firefox when click inside input field, the calendar will be show, but on Chrome the calendar do not show, I have to click arrow button.

[image]

How can I make it work as Firefox?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

clean cache memory and try it again or try it another version of firefox. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I tested the link you post in my Google Chrome version 65.0.3325.181 and it works perfectly.

Try to update and restart your navigator and if it doesn't work, clean the caches.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 69.

Answer (score -1):

once check your installed extension in chrome, if you have any additional virtual keyboard etc.. turn off and checked

I have faced the same issue only my system date field not working other all system it working, even in mobile also work properly, so once I setting check with the extension now it;'s working